# Simple PHP syntax issue

Tags: php

I am sure this is super easy for someone to answer but I am brain-dead.

```
$return_html.= '<a class="cat_link" href="'.$category_url.'">''<h5 class="header_line ''</a>';
```

What is up with this syntax? It throws an error. Cheers.

Comment: Try this: $return_html.= '<a class="cat_link" href="'.$category_url.'"><h5 class="header_line"</a>';

Comment: There's two single quotes between the `<a>` and `<h5>` tags. also, the h5 tag is never properly closed and there's annother two single quotes in between it and the closing tag for the `<a>`

Comment: Try this     $return_html.= "<a class='cat_link' href='".$category_url."'><h5 class='header_line'</a>";

Comment: Those answers both break the site so here is the code surrounding the issue

Comment: if(!empty($link))
   {
    $category_url = get_category_link($category);
    $return_html.= '<a class="cat_link" href="'.$category_url.'">'.__( 'Latest In', THEMEDOMAIN ).'&nbsp;'.get_cat_name($category).'</a>';
   }
   
   $return_html.= '<h5 class="header_line ';

Comment: Update the question with your code and include your error message. No reason to make us guess at what issue you are running into.

Comment: @RyanVincent unfortunately that potential solution also blows up the site

Comment: Error is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING"

Comment: The answer below doesn't resolve your issue? Sounds like the same behavior here, https://eval.in/466515.

Answer (score 2):

```
'">''<h5
```

You end a string literal, then you immediately start another string literal with no operator between them.

(Then you do it again near the end).

Comment: You said the problem, but you didn't say the solution... need to add that `.` concatenation operator in between the two.

Comment: I think a better solution than concatenation is just removing the quotes. They are doing nothing aside from breaking the OPs code. `'">' . '<h5` outputs the same as `'"><h5`

Comment: @Jonathan Yes I fixed with this help.

Comment: @chris85 Yeah, that's easier.